# Doubly Linked List Adding Pointers (Java)

Tags: java, pointers, linked-list, addition, space

I understand that there is a space saving technique when implementing a double linked list where you can add pointers. I have been trying to implement that data structure. Im not entirely sure how you would be able to add pointers. The code of a standard doubly linked list looks as this:

```
class DLink<E> 
{
  private E element;         // Value for this node
  private DLink<E> next;     // Pointer to next node in list
  private DLink<E> prev;     // Pointer to previous node

  /** Constructors */
  DLink(E it, DLink<E> p, DLink<E> n)
  { 
    element = it;  
    prev = p; 
    next = n; 
  }

  DLink(DLink<E> p, DLink<E> n)
  { 
    prev = p; 
    next = n; 
  }

  /** Get and set methods for the data members */
  DLink<E> next() 
  { 
    return next; 
  }

  DLink<E> setNext(DLink<E> nextval)
  { 
    return next = nextval; 
  }

  DLink<E> prev() 
  { 
    return prev; 
  }

  DLink<E> setPrev(DLink<E> prevval)
  { 
    return prev = prevval; 
  }

  E element() 
  { 
    return element; 
  }

  E setElement(E it) 
  { 
    return element = it; 
  }
}
```

Here is what I read online.

> "There is a space-saving technique that can be employed to eliminate the additional space requirement, though it will complicate the implementation and be somewhat slower. Thus, this is an example of a space/time tradeoff. It is based on observing that, if we store the sum of two values, then we can get either value back by subtracting the other. Of course, to recover one of the values out of the stored summation, the other value must be supplied. A pointer to the first node in the list, along with the value of one of its two link fields, will allow access to all of the remaining nodes of the list in order. This is because the pointer to the node must be the same as the value of the following node's prev pointer, as well as the previous node's next pointer. It is possible to move down the list breaking apart the summed link fields as though you were opening a zipper."
>   Source: http://algoviz.org/OpenDSA/Books/OpenDSA/html/ListDouble.html

Comment: Pointers? In Java?

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit confused with that also. I had found that online. I put up the original link. I also quoted the part about adding pointers. That should help understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: Link results in a 404. The attempt here is to decrease the number of nodes by storing two `element`s in one in the form of a sum. When retrieving, you of course subtract, but from what exactly isn't clear. The site also uses the term pointer to describe simple java references.

Comment: So rather than combining the references, I am supposed to be combining the elements? That makes more sense. I thought I was supposed to be combining pointers (references).

Comment: @user3284531 That trick that they mention as a "space saving" technique is used to swap the value of two variables without using a third variable. It's not at all related to linked lists. If you had a doubly-linked list with two pointers stored in a single node reference, you'd *still* have to keep one of the pointers around to be able to discover the other one. So you wouldn't save any space, and then you'd have the problem of figuring out which pointer pointed to which node. It's absolutely nonsensical. I would stop reading that tutorial right now. Get a book on data structures.

Comment: Interestingly, my java book had the exact same description of this type of data structure. Word for word.

Comment: @user3284531 there are better books. Search SO for best books on data structures and algorithms and you'll find some good ones.